# Select Menu Object

Tags: php, oop, tostring

I am trying to create a select menu object that I can reuse:

`class Mentor {

```
var $nid;
var $level_id;
var $output;

public function __construct($nid)
{   
include 'con.php'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
'SELECT a.uid, pp.fName, pp.lName FROM primary_profile as pp LEFT JOIN attributes as a ON pp.uid = a.uid WHERE nid = :nid AND :level_id = level_id');
$stmt->execute(array(':nid' => $nid, ':level_id' => 3));

$output .= '<select name="mentor_id">';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$output .='<option value="'.$row['uid'].'">'.$row['fName']. ' ' .$row['lName'].'</option>';
}
$output .= '</select>';

return $output;
}

public function __toString(){   
    return $output;
}
```

} `

On my page I am calling:

`$mentor_select = new Mentor($nid);
echo $mentor_select;`

It works if I put on the page outside the class but in the class I get an error:
Catchable fatal error: Method Mentor::__toString() must return a string value

I know this means __toString must output a string but as far as I can see $output is a string...

I am new to OOP.  Please help me with what I am missing

Comment: Usually include 'db_or_config_file.php';  goes/could be seen at the beginning of the file where class is defined. Also that isn't necessary.

Comment: Constructors should not explicitly return values. They are used when you instantiate the class. I will post you a simplified example how to use your class in better way.

Comment: Thank you Whirlwind... I Looked over your Class and it does make more sense the way you have it... but I don't understand where the while loop comes in to create the menu options

I still need to wrap my mind around constructors I will try to find some more tutorials but information seems scarce.

Comment: Good place for creating menu items and return the output would be in getOutput method. Leave constructor for initialization  stuff and basic setup.

Comment: I also need to understand getters and setters better as well I will continue to try and find tutorials....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$output =  null. You need to set it as a class variable inside your functions by using $this->output

```
public function __construct($nid)
{   
$this->output .= '<select name="mentor_id">';
$this->output .= '</select>';
```

//return $this->output;
   }

```
public function __toString(){   
    return $this->output;
}
```

Comment: Hi David,
I did try that:

 `$output .= '<select name="mentor_id">';
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $output .='<option value="'.$row['uid'].'">'.$row['fName']. ' ' .$row['lName'].'</option>';
 }
 $output .= '</select>';
 
 //return $output;
 }
 
 public function __toString(){ 
  return $this->output;
 }
}`

but got the same error

Comment: half way there......` $output .='<option value="'` you need to set the output variable for the class by using `$this->output='...'` as well or there is nothing to return!

Comment: Thanks for your help David..  I can see I still have a lot of learning to do the get the OOP thing straight in my head

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Mentor {

    //Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member
    //Also you can declare members of a class as protected, and public. Read about that.
    private $nid;
    private $level_id;
    private $output;

    public function __construct($nid)
    {
        $this->level_id = 0;//You can initialize properties to their default values here
        $this->nid = $nid;
        $this->output = "output value $this->nid";

        //return $this->output; constructors should not return values explicitly
        //they are used to instantiate the class
    }

    public function __toString(){   
        return $this->output;
    }

    public function getOutput(){
        return $this->output;//property output is private, so we define a public method which allows us to read it's value outside this class.
    }
}

    $mentor = new Mentor(3);// you don't need to return value from your constructor, because you have defined __toString magic method.
    echo $mentor;

?>
```